# AS3: Storing array of custom classes in a Locally Shared Object (LSO)

Tags: actionscript-3, lso

I am having problems storing an array of objects, all of which are the same custom class in an LSO and then reloading that array from the LSO without losing the class type of the objects in the list.

I know how to store a single object of a custom class and load it withe the correct class type using the `registerClassAlias()` function, but I cannot seem to apply this to arrays of objects.

I am trying to save an array called messageList. Each element is a custom class GameMessage with a property called gameLevel.  After I load the LSO I am trying to do something like

```
trace("0th message is from level " + GameMessage(messageList[0]).gameLevel);
```

And I am getting an exception of like this:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@90fdfa1 to GameMessage.

I have registered the GameMessage class using

```
registerClassAlias("GameMessage", GameMessage);
```

and everything works if rather than a list of messages I try and save/load a single message.

Any help on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure you can do custom classes like this. Post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like The_asMan said I don't think you can do custom classes, only the basic datatypes from AS3. What you could do in your custom classes is set helper functions like fromObject(object) and toObject():Object in the class to help you convert them.